# MsiViewFetch "SELECT * FROM `Property`" is successful, but returns "Incorrect function." in C++

Tags: c++, installation, windows-installer

I want to read the Propery table of an msi-file.
The table is shown correclty.

This is the call and (part of the) output:

```
>ReadMsiProperties.exe evince-2.32.0.145.msi
(MsiOpenDatabase The operation completed successfully.)
(MsiViewFetch Incorrect function.)  WixAppFolder = WixPerUserFolder
(MsiViewFetch Incorrect function.)  WixUIRMOption = UseRM
(MsiViewFetch Incorrect function.)  WIXUI_INSTALLDIR = APPLICATIONFOLDER
(MsiViewFetch Incorrect function.)  ALLUSERS = 2
```

MsiViewFetch is succesfull but returns "Incorrect function." 
This is error code 1 (ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION) from winerror.h

I assume I miss something and would not like to ignore the error.

I have tried to debug, but it seems I cannot debug into MsiViewFetch.

Does someone have a hint?

Thank you,
Markus

This is the code:

```
// Requirements: Add Msi.lib to "Resource Files" 

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <msi.h>
#include <msiquery.h>

MSIHANDLE hDB;
MSIHANDLE hViewSELECT;
MSIHANDLE hRecord; 
TCHAR  svPropname[256];
TCHAR  svPropvalue[256]; 
DWORD nBuffer;
UINT errorI;
_TCHAR errorM[256];


void errorCode2char (UINT error, _TCHAR *buf) {
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, error, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 256, NULL);
    // chop \r\n
    if (buf[_tcslen(buf)-1] = '\n') buf[_tcslen(buf)-1] = '\0';
    if (buf[_tcslen(buf)-1] = '\r') buf[_tcslen(buf)-1] = '\0';
}

void _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    errorI = MsiOpenDatabase(argv[1], MSIDBOPEN_READONLY, &hDB);
    errorCode2char(errorI, errorM);
    printf("(MsiOpenDatabase %S)\n", errorM);
    if (errorI != ERROR_SUCCESS) return;

    MsiDatabaseOpenView(hDB, _T("SELECT `Property`, `Value` FROM `Property`"), &hViewSELECT);
    MsiViewExecute(hViewSELECT, NULL);
    while (errorI = MsiViewFetch (hViewSELECT, &hRecord)  != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) { // *errorI <-- Incorrect function.
        errorCode2char(errorI, errorM);
        nBuffer = (DWORD)256; MsiRecordGetString(hRecord, 1, svPropname, &nBuffer);
        nBuffer = (DWORD)256; MsiRecordGetString(hRecord, 2, svPropvalue, &nBuffer);
        printf("(MsiViewFetch %S)  %S = %S\n", errorM, svPropname, svPropvalue);
    }
    MsiViewClose(hViewSELECT);
    MsiDatabaseCommit(hDB);
    MsiCloseHandle(hViewSELECT);
    MsiCloseHandle(hDB);
}
```

Comment: On first inspection, this looks okay, but something must be wrong. What do your calls to `MsiDatabaseOpenView` and `MsiViewExecute` return? If `MsiDatabaseOpenView` succeeds, what's in `hViewSELECT`?

Comment: Hi Michael, the root cause is C++, not Msi. I need to say **while ((errorI = MsiViewFetch(hView, &hRecord)) != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)** though I don't yet understand why. Regarding your question: everything worked, only the value of errorI was distorted :-)

Comment: Why are not precedence rules saving me? **while (a = b != c){}** is different from **while ((a = b) != c){}**.

Comment: To my surprise, comparison (!= and ==) has precedence over direct assignment (=). 

Therefore, a statement

    while (a = b != c)

is interpreted as 

    while (a = (b != c))

Which is not my intention.

The code given in the question is corrected by inserting brackets

    while ((a = b) != c)

explicetely

    while ((errorI = MsiViewFetch(hView, &hRecord)) != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)

Comment: Ah, subtle! I should have caught that, but I was too busy looking at the flow of Msi calls. Looks like you can answer this now, but I wouldn't think this question is likely to help others much.

Comment: So I am learning C++, MsiOpenView and Stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

A coding mistakes distorts the return code of MsiViewFetch, which undistorted is 0 (for ERROR_SUCCESS).

In c++, comparison (!=) has precedence over direct assignment (=).

Therefore, a statement

```
while (a = b != c)
```

is interpreted as

```
while (a = (b != c))
```

Which is not my intention.

The program is corrected by inserting brackets

```
while ((a = b) != c)
```

explicetely

```
while ((errorI = MsiViewFetch(hViewSELECT, &hRecord)) != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake where errorI hold,return value of API(MsiOpenDatabase)

```
while(errorI = MsiViewFetch (hViewSELECT, &hRecord)  != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
```

Using `while (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != MsiViewFetch(hView, &hRecord))` Could resolve this error.

Comment: Feb 23, 2014 I published  my solution, namely to use brackets around the errorI assignment, see below.  In your suggestion you omit the errorI variable